# How to run RavenDb in embedded mode?

Tags: c#, ravendb, embedded-database

[Ravendb documentation](http://ravendb.net/documentation/docs-client-api-index) says to simply set the DataDirectory name before initializing the DocumentStore, but DocumentStore doesn't have a DataDirectory property :(

```
var documentStore = new DocumentStore  {  
      DataDirectory = "path/to/database/directory"  
};
documentStore.Initialize();
```

The code above doesn't compile :(

---

Ok, my bad...

I was using Raven.Client-3.5.dll, you have to use Raven.Client.dll

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yeah - hosting RavenDB involves

- Dynamic support
- A whole suite of
  dependencies

This means that you can't run it in 3.5 and you can't run it using the Lightweight client :)

Comment: I've actually written a quick entry on the subject if anybody reaches this point again: http://codeofrob.com/archive/2010/09/28/ravendb-image-gallery-project-ii-setting-up.aspx